# Change IntelliJ formatting default behavior

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting

One of the projects I am working expects '.' to be formatted in the following way:

```
 Foo().
  Fum().
  Fee();
```

By default, IntelliJ formats '.' the following way, which violates the standards I am asked to follow and can not change.

```
 Foo()
  .Fum()
  .Fee();
```

How do I make intellij not place a . after a whitespace, which is explicitly forbidden?

I went through various guides in java style settings and did not find any option that resolved the issue. I asked people I respected and they too did not know of any solution.